# Remove border from Flutter TextField

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to remove the border outline from this TextField in flutter, but can't seem to figure the semantic way to do it.

```
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
                        ),
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Completely blanking on this.

*edit need to keep BorderRadius.cicrular active

**edit edit looking to remove the black line around this TextInput

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Had to modify `border` to this:

```
 border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                            width: 0,
                            style: BorderStyle.none,
                          ),
                          ),
```

To maintain `BorderRadius.circular` and also dump the outline.

Comment: borderSide: BorderSide.none does the job but it's shorter and more readable

Answer (score 12):

You can remove border outline `TextField`

Here some example may help you:

```
 TextFormField(
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
            enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
            errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
            disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,),


TextField(
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
        border: InputBorder.none,
        focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
        enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
        errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
        disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
        hintText: "Hint here"),)
```

Answer (score 3):

In your textfield, do the following:

```
 TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide.none,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(17)
         ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

this will keep your textfield circular, and will remove the borders

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 2):

Just change `border : InputBorder.none`

Comment: woops should add, need to keep the BorderRadius.circular active

Comment: can you show the design, please? i am just confused about your question

Comment: no probs. just uploaded an image to the original post to help explain what i'm trying to get rid of.

Comment: inside ```OutlineInputBorder```, try add this
```borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)
```

Comment: No luck with this. BorderSide doesn't appear to style any part of the border.